# Run c++ gcloud or virtual machine with personal computer closed

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, gcloud, slurm

I am really new bee to the world of programming. I have small neural network code in c++. My learning will take really long time (~3hours). I have no outputs to console, just writing everything to file. I created a instance in gcloud (virtual machine) and created a output file  (executable) for my source code. I want to run it on my gcloud (virtual machine) which is on even my personal computer is turned off. I want to find out how to run it.
1. Main issue is closing of my personal computer is shutting of down my virtual machine terminal.
2. Installing slurm in gcloud is not at all friendly.

Appreciate if you can dum it down. (Main task: Run my source code in c++ on virtual machine with my personal system off). Let me know if I need to provide any more details.

Comment: Take a look at tmux. It will keep your terminal running even when the ssh connection gets terminated.

Comment: Tmux has ever low help available mainly in c++. Any super useful links will be appreciated.

Comment: You are confunding C++ programming and Shell scripting. When logged on a remote Shell terminal, for instance gcloud, you shall create a new session of tmux. Such session works as a new terminal in which you may run your C++ compiled code but will not be terminated when you ssh'd out. 

This looks like a good starting point: https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux (take a look at the Session Handling section).